# Beats phenomenon-amplitude variation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, superposition

[Confusion in understanding the concept of beats](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161756/) does not answer my question.

For amplitude, there are two terms viz., $\cos(\frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2}t)$ and $\sin(\frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}t)$. Now taking this question:

[image]

While dealing with amplitude for a particular $x$, why are we considering only the first term, i.e, $\cos(\frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2}t)$?

We say that the time period of the first term is more than that of the second term. Shouldn't that mean that the variation should be 'more' dependent on the second term than on the first term?

What I have seen in textbooks solutions is opposite. For example in this one, all the manipulations are done using the first term only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are beats formed when frequencies combine?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296601)

Comment: This could be because you should consider some kind of "time-averaging" (such as RMS values of some kind), which, based on the time constant, could "reject" the high-frequency component (acts like a low-pass filter). This is just speculation though.

Answer (score 1):

The figure below shows the result of combining a wave of sound $f_1 = 15$ kHz, and another one of frequency $f_2 = 17$ kHz, the amplitude for both is 1 (arbitrary units).

[image]

The red line is just the sum of the two waves, the dashed blue line shows a wave of frequency $f_{\rm pulse} = |f_2 - f_1| = 2$ kHz, this is the frequency of the wave responsible for amplitude modulation of the sound you hear. Note that the higher frequency $f_1 + f_2 = 32$ kHz is outside the hearing range, so you will not hear it.

Comment: Okay, well what I don't get is, why most of the questions are done using the first term, aka, $\cos(\frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2}t)$?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan Because that is the term that describes the modulation/beats, or is your question related to the 1/2 factor in there?

Comment: Well yeah, in the second part of the question, only after considering only the first term in amplitude variation, I am able to get the answer.

Comment: There is no 32 kHz or 2 kHz (those are only caused by nonlinearities and are at least 40 dB weaker than the 15 and 17 kHz).

Answer (score 0):

> While dealing with amplitude for a particular , why are we considering only the first term, i.e, $\cos\left(\frac{\omega_1−\omega_2}{2}t\right)$?

The amplitude is the *product* of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms. Since $\sin(x) \leq 1 \,\,\forall x$, the product of the two terms can never exceed $A\cos(\ldots)$. It will at most times be smaller, and oscillate between $\pm A\cos(\ldots)$ with the frequency of the $\sin$ term. So whenever $\cos\left(\frac{\omega_1−\omega_2}{2}t\right) < \sqrt{2}$, it doesn't matter what the argument of the $\sin$ is, the intensity will always be too small to detect it.